# Is there a way to break out of deeply nested async calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following pattern in my code.

```js
function serverGet(callback) {
   return callback("this is the real data");
}

function getData(callback) {
   var c1= true, c2, c3, c4; //c1 set to true as illustration to make snippet run
   if (c1) {
      serverGet(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
          return callback(data);  //line 10
      })
    } else {
      //other conditions
      if (c2) {
        //....
      } else {
          if (c3) {
            //....
          } else {
              if (c4) {
                // ....
              } else {
                  // ....
                }
}

function main() {
  getData(function(data) {
    console.log("Finally, the data is: "+data);
  });
}

main();
```

Is there a way at line 10 to return back to `main` so as to avoid all those if/else block and deep indentations?

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: What do you mean by "return back to main"?

Comment: I don't see what if-then-else blocks have to do with `serverGet` being asynchronous?

Comment: @guest271314: Exiting the `getData` function and returning to where it was called in `main`. I am trying to avoid many `else` blocks (and lots of indentations) in `getData` to handle different conditions.

Comment: @OldGeezer Please show your full, real code. I don't see and `else` blocks yet. How are "different conditions" handled? And why is `someCondition` constantly true?

Comment: You can use `Promise` constructor, returned from `getData()` call, `.then()` and `.catch()` within `main` function. It is not clear how `if..else` statements are related to Question _"Is there a way to break out of deeply nested async calls?"_?

Comment: I think he wants some form of _nonlocal return_.

Comment: If your problem is the indentation, just use `else if` without the block. I don't see what callbacks vs. returning has to do with that.

Comment: Seriously, your code doesn't make sense. Unless you show exactly what you're trying to accomplish with a real use case, nobody will be able to help you. for instance, `var c1= true, c2, c3, c4;` what are these conditions? will you set them statically in your code? are they candidates to be used as params for your function? I don't know. Nobody knows... help us to help you. ;)

Answer (score -1):

<s>Promises are just syntax sugar for callbacks. You can do it in the same way as in case of promises.</s>

On line 10 throw an exception and
a) let it bubble through all callbacks so you will have try/catch block everywhere
b) catch it at top level callback

a) is better because you can do necessary cleanup at all levels

Comment: Exceptions don't bubble backwards in time from asynchronous callbacks. Or did I understand something wrong here?

Comment: True, sorry, it must be done in same way as in promises - by error callback. So no, it is not possible to "return" directly as the sync code calling the async code is already done.